# Problem launching TYPO3 via DDEV on Linux: Call to undefined function Composer\Autoload\includeFile()

Tags: linux, docker-compose, typo3, typo3-extensions, ddev

I need to setup ddev with TYPO3 10.4 on public server (I know it's not a good practise, it's just to show a demo to the client). On my local machine (Windows + WSL2 + Docker + DDEV + Composer) everything works perfect, but when I start my project on the Linux suddenly there are some errors.

I have checked permissions, there is a newest version of composer, docker and ddev installed.

Errors:

```
[ Error ]
Call to undefined function Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
```

---

```
Failed to execute command vendor/bin/typo3cms extension:activate site: exit status 1
```

---

```
Task failed: Exec command 'cd frontend && npm ci && npm run prod' in container/service 'web': exit status 130
```

---

```
Task failed: Exec command 'vendor/bin/typo3cms database:updateschema' in container/service 'web': exit status 1
```

It looks like it can't execute commands, but I can't find any meaningful reason why. I will be glad for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install most new version of typo3-console.

Your problem is described here:
https://github.com/TYPO3-Console/TYPO3-Console/issues/1081